# import particles as particle system?

Tags: import

Any way to import particles from a 3rd party software and have them import as a blender particle system so I can use them to scatter objects?

I'm using Houdini, so if I can bring in the density, scale, rotation attributes etc that would be great.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures

Comment: Well, I thought I'd found a workaround by importing particles as alembic, in which case they come through as vertices, and then applying a particle hair system set to vertices as the distributin method.

Only problem is though that I can't find a way to import the vertex normals ready for the scatter system.  Possible?